# How to "audit" imported Objective-C methods/functions for optionals, like Apple did?

Tags: objective-c, swift, option-type

By default, Objective-C method and function arguments and return types that are object-pointer types are imported into Swift as implicitly-unwrapped optionals (`!`). The same was true with all Cocoa APIs in Swift in the first Xcode 6 beta.

However, in later betas and release versions, Apple has been on an ongoing process of "auditing" those and converting them into either regular optionals (`?`) or non-optionals, depending on whether that argument or return can be `nil` or not.

My question is, is there a way to do this with my own methods and functions imported from Objective-C? Is there some kind of keyword that I can put next to object-pointer types in mhy Objective-C declarations to make them imported into Swift as regular optionals or non-optionals?